# Split function not working in UNIX

Tags: function, unix, split

I'm trying to run a split on a file where the filename has spaces in it.

I can't seem to get it to work. So I have the following

```
SOURCE_FILE="test file.txt"
split -l 100 $SOURCE_FILE
```

Now I've tried enclosing the `$SOURCE_FILE` in `"` with no luck:

```
split -l 100 "\""$SOURCE_FILE"\""
```

or even

```
split -l 100 '"'$SOURCE_FILE'"'
```

I'm still getting:

```
usage: split [-l line_count] [-a suffix_length] [file [name]]
   or: split -b number[k|m] [-a suffix_length] [file [name]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying too hard! A single set of double quotes will suffice:

```
split -l 100 "$SOURCE_FILE"
```

You want the arguments to split to look like this:

```
-l
100
test file.txt
```

The commands you were trying both yield these arguments:

```
-l
100
"test
file.txt"
```

As in, they are equivalent to this incorrect command:

```
split -l 100 '"test' 'file.txt"'
```

Comment: Dude I'm going to kill myself :( I thought that would insert the actual word`"$SOURCE_FILE"` instead of the variable. FML

Comment: Ah, yes, you can use variable names inside double quotes. Just not inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could insert a backslash to escape the embedded space:

```
SOURCE_FILE=test\ file.txt
split -l 100 "$SOURCE_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you tried just "$SOURCE_FILE" without the fancy escaping tricks?

I think I would try cat-ing the file into split, maybe split just has issues with files with spaces in their name, or maybe it is really pissed off about something other than the space.